# how to get and set the list of user names shown in recent changes as environment variable in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I need to get the list of user names from the recent changes section in jenkins job and add as a argument to an external script. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traverse through [jenkins_home_dir]/jobs/[JOB]/builds/[buildIds]/changelog.xml and grab anything in between `<author></author>`